# ERC721 Transfer Event in Constructor

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

I thought that when you mint an `ERC721` Token in the `Constructor` of your smart-contract it will ***not*** emit the `Transfer` event.

I'm thinking this cause of what's written in the official `ERC721 EIP` documentation:

```
    ///  Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs
    ///  may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer
```

(You can read the full docs here: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)

I supposed the key is the wording "***may be*** created and assigned without emitting Transfer"... Meaning it's not automatic, but it ***can*** be made to happen.

So how do we get this "***may be***" to actually **BE**?
Cause when I do my minting in the `constructor` the `Transfer` event is being emitted every single time (or 100 times in my case.)

Here's my constructor code:

```
constructor() ERC721("myNFT", "mNFT") {
  
  // Mint 100 NFTs in a FOR loop:
  for(uint8 NFTCounter = 0; NFTCounter < 100; NFTCounter ++) {
     _safeMint(msg.sender, NFTCounter, "");
  }
}
```

So why is `Transfer` being emitted - and how can I prevent it from being emitted?

(And ere's the full blurb from the docs:)

```
interface ERC721 /* is ERC165 */ {
    /// @dev This emits when ownership of any NFT changes by any mechanism.
    ///  This event emits when NFTs are created (`from` == 0) and destroyed
    ///  (`to` == 0). Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs
    ///  may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer. At the time of
    ///  any transfer, the approved address for that NFT (if any) is reset to none.

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think because what you read and what you use are not the same. I assume you're using latest EIP721 from openzeppelin which is referred here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L241

You can take a look in this code: _safeMint -> _mint -> _update -> emit event

So whenever _safeMint is called and success, one event will be emitted, don't have any condition.

`and how can I prevent it from being emitted?` => Override it by yourself

Comment: ok but *HOW* do I override the `_mint` method? It doesn't have `override` in it's signature - like say the `supportsInterface()` method does, meaning I can't rewrite/`override` it in my own parent-contract like I could with `supportsInterface()`.  And if instead I rewrite it in the original ERC721 contract - by just removing the `emit Transfer` line, would it still be compliant? (And actually I shouldn't remove `emit Transfer` cause I do still need to `emit Transfer` on all upcoming regular mints that will happen outside of my `constructor.`  So...how do you propose to `override`?